# Spectral line in the gamma range of the gamma-ray burst

Tags: astrophysics

I would like to know about any research that is conducted to get spectral lines in the gamma range of gamma-ray burst. I try to find data or information about these typical spectral lines. Is it possible that absorption lines in the spectrum of a star or gamma ray burst which occur at different wavelength (up to the gamma range) shifted by different amount ? If those lines are shifted by different amount for different wavelength, the redshift of that star depend on the wavelength.

Comment: I can't quite follow your question. Are you asking whether absorption lines (or presumably emission lines) from gamma ray busts and identified gamma ray burst sources show different amounts of redshift that depend on their observed wavelength?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

GRB observers commonly use the [Band function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst_emission_mechanisms#GRBs_and_internal_shocks) to model GRB spectra. It has only a single energy scale, and that scale apparently depends on the GRB jet energy and the angle from which we observe the jet, so it cannot be used as a standard to determine a redshift.

There have been many searches for spectral lines, with some reports of marginal detections in the range 20-40 keV a few decades ago. I don't think anybody thinks those credible anymore. My own opinion is that they were instrumental artifacts reflecting the difficulties of calibration and background determination in that energy range.